# Why is this code not preserving the clipboard?

Tags: c#, clipboard

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(Clipboard.GetDataObject(), true);
}
```

This is just about the simplest test I can imagine of using the `DataObject` clipboard methods, but if copy some text from notepad then run this application, I can no longer paste that text after the application exits. There are no exceptions thrown. Using an application called ClipView, I can see that the text is gone from the clipboard.

The namespace I'm using is the one from System.Windows.Forms. As you can see, this is a console application rather than windows forms application, so it's possible that that is behind the problem. But if so, I would like to understand why.

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, this is just a test, and my actual objective with the clipboard is more complicated. I realize if I only cared about text I could use the methods specifically for text.

**EDIT 2**

While the method documentation leaves quite a bit to desire, [this Code Project article](http://codeproject.com/Articles/2207/Clipboard-handling-with-NET) and [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/637ys738%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) both seem to indicate that calling `Clipboard.SetDataObject` with a `DataObject` should work as expected, adding all the data in that data object with the correct formats.

Comment: Despite their names, GetDataObject and SetDataObject might not be symmetric functions. GetDataObject returns an `IDataObject` that can be used to retrieve the real payload, whereas SetDataObject expects some serializable payload. (This is what I gathered from the documentation.)

Comment: @Heinzi Yes, it is a bit unclear. Going by the last part of this article though, I think `SetDataObject` should be able to correctly handle an `IDataObject`: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2207/Clipboard-handling-with-NET

Comment: you have to do this Clipboard.SetDataObject(Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Text), true); ..you where setting the idataobject itselft as the data and not the data it contained.

Comment: @terrybozzio What if I have multiple different data types that I want on the clipboard simultaneously, as in the link from my previous comment?

Comment: then please refer to this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/637ys738(v=vs.110).aspx - in the section To add data to the Clipboard in multiple formats.

Comment: @terrybozzio Right, I did, and that includes, in its example, `Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);`, where `data` is a `DataObject`. Hence thinking that should be a valid thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs5ebdfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the `Clipboard.SetDataObject` method "Clears the Clipboard **and then** places data on it and specifies whether the data should remain after the application exits" (emphasis mine).

There appears to be a behind-the-scenes timing issue regarding when the code in `SetDataObject` actually retrieves the data from the Windows Clipboard. If the `DataObject` returned by `GetDataObject` defers its read, and `SetDataObject`'s clearing code executes before calling `GetData` on the `GetDataObject` return, then the clipboard could be empty at the time `SetDataObject` tries to set its data.

(My first thought was that the clearing happens before the call to `Clipboard.GetDataObject` occurs; however, as the commenters below note, the arguments to any method call are evaluated prior to that method call occurring.)

Comment: Are you saying that a method is invoked before its argument is resolved?  I don't see how that can be true.

Comment: Obviously impossible yes, arguments are resolved first

Comment: Well it's not before the call to `GetDataObject` occurs (as the above comments explain), but I believe the `DataObject` itself might defer retrieving the data from the clipboard until its methods are called... in fact I'm almost certain that is the case. So this is a plausible explanation.

Comment: This would be a explanation: Since you are just receiving a *reference* by *GetDataObject*, the actual content is erased when entering the SetDataObject - and then the reference points to nothing. This would also explain, why the manual copy ("new" object) does work.

Comment: If you update this answer to be more accurate (as per the comments), I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked, if your application is running with enough permissions to access the clipboard?

Try to add the following lines of code in front of your clipboard thing and see if you get a security exception:

```
IPermission permission = new UIPermission(PermissionState.None);
permission.Clipboard = UIPermissionClipboard.AllClipboard;
permission.Demand();
```

I have tested the code and for me it shows the same behaviour.
However, manually backuping each ClipBoard Entry and restoring it Manually works just fine.
(button 1 stores it, button 2 restores it)

```
Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    IDataObject o = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    foreach (string format in o.GetFormats())
    {
        d.Add(format, o.GetData(format));
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataObject o = new DataObject();

    foreach (string format in d.Keys)
    {
        o.SetData(format, d[format]);
    }

    Clipboard.SetDataObject(o);

}
```